# Bootstrap nav not centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a Bootstrap menu that that is slightly aligned to the left for some reason, I can't debug it.  It doesn't have any rows, but the container is fluid and changing this to fixed makes it unresponsive in mobiles.

This is the live example. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjKbQM

This is the HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="border:1px solid red";>
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">UP</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th" aria-hidden="true"></span> DEVIS GRATUIT</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Nos Ressource <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
        <a href="/fiches-conseils" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/578">Toutes nos ressources</a>
              </li>
          <li>
        <a href="/fiches-conseils" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/578">Fiches conseils</a>
              </li>
          <li>
        <a href="/nos-fiches-metiers" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/1099">Fiches métiers</a>
              </li>
          <li>
        <a href="/foire-aux-questions" title="FAQ" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/1079">Foire aux questions</a>
              </li>
          <li>
        <a href="/revue-de-presse" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/480">Revue de presse</a>
              </li>
          <li>
        <a href="https://blog.cacomptepourmoi.fr/" target="_blank">Le Blog</a>
              </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Nos Fonctionalites <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
        <a href="/nos-fonctionnalites" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/474">Toutes nos fonctionnalités</a>
              </li>
          <li class="">
        <a href="/nos-fonctionnalites#indicateurs" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/474">Mes indicateurs</a>
              </li>
          <li class="">
        <a href="/nos-fonctionnalites#macompta" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/474">Ma comptabilité </a>
              </li>
          <li class="">
        <a href="/nos-fonctionnalites#devisfactures" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/474">Mes devis et factures</a>
              </li>
          <li class="">
        <a href="/nos-fonctionnalites#monbudget" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/474">Mon budget</a>
              </li>
          <li>
        <a href="/nos-fonctionnalites#socialrh" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/474">Mon social-RH</a>
              </li>
          <li class="">
        <a href="/nos-fonctionnalites#coffrefort" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/474">Mon coffre-fort</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Accounts</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Notre Cabinet <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
        <a href="/qui-sommes-nous" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/1088">Tout sur notre cabinet</a>
              </li>
          <li class="">
        <a href="/qui-sommes-nous" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/1088">Qui sommes-nous ?</a>
              </li>
          <li>
        <a href="/pourquoi-nous-choisir" title="Choisir Ça Compte pour Moi" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/669">Pourquoi nous choisir ?</a>
              </li>
          <li>
        <a href="/ca-compte-pour-moi-en-5-etapes" title="Les étapes pour devenir client" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/1089">Comment devenir client ?</a>
              </li>
          <li>
        <a href="/notre-equipe" title="Découvrez notre équipe" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/630">Notre équipe</a>
              </li>
          <li>
        <a href="/vos-questions-nos-reponses" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/1087">Vos questions, nos réponses</a>
              </li>
          <li class="">
        <a href="/temoignages-clients" title="Témoignages de nos clients" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/969">Témoignages clients</a>
              </li>
          <li class="">
        <a href="/recrutement" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/446">Recrutement</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Nos Solutions <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
        <a href="/nos-solutions" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/374">Toutes nos solutions</a>
              </li>
          <li class="">
        <a href="/nos-solutions/tpe" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/392">TPE / Consultants</a>
              </li>
          <li>
        <a href="/nos-solutions/createur" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/388">Porteurs de projet</a>
              </li>
          <li>
        <a href="/nos-solutions/sci-location-meublee" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/497">SCI / Locations meublées</a>
              </li>
          <li class="">
        <a href="/nos-solutions/paye-salaire" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/394">Paye des salariés</a>
              </li>
          <li class="">
        <a href="/nos-solutions/profession-liberale" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/757">Professions Libérales</a>
              </li>
          <li class="">
        <a href="/nos-solutions/association" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/761">Associations</a>
              </li>
          <li class="">
        <a href="/nos-solutions" title="Les solutions de comptabilité en ligne" target="" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/374">Toutes nos solutions</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

And this is the css :

```
.navbar-default {
  font-size: 1.15em;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px; 
  background: #021a2f !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #cbf0ff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #002433;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1px -1px 8px #b3e9ff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  background-color: #004059;
  color: white;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #002433;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
}

.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #004059;
  color: white;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  background-color: #004059;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  background-color: #004059;
  color:white;
}

.dropdown-menu .divider {
    height: 1px;
    margin: 9px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #003246;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { 
  .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    background-color: #006b96;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
  }

  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  .dropdown-menu .divider {
    height: 1px;
    margin: 9px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #005577;
  }
}
```

How can I make the menus be centered without loosing the responsiveness of the navbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below css to get

```
.nav.customCl {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

And use this class in following html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav customCl"
```

**[codepen link](https://codepen.io/Lokeshg27/pen/awKwZz?editors=1100#0)**

Comment: Still aligned to the left

Comment: it's working fine i added codepen link in my answer check it

Comment: It is not centered. I don't know what browser you are using